# Drupal: How to integrate AES Encryption module with CCK?

Tags: drupal, encryption, aes

AES Encryption (http://drupal.org/project/aes) module comes with an easy developer API

```
$encrypted_data => aes_encrypt("mydata");
$decrypted_to_plain_text => aes_decrypt($encrypted_data);
```

I was thinking how one could integrate this with CCK, so data stored into the DB is encrypted just before storage, and decrypted on retrieval. The way I imagine the  UI is to have a simple checkbox on the field setup page asking whether to store the data as encrypted.

This way, one could protect its database, in case hackers get a hold of it. Think of the recent email marketing website breaches, where the entire userbase was spammed.
http://www.reuters.com/article/2011/04/05/idUS100003661220110405

Comment: If I look at the drupal code for that, I can see it stores the AES key in the database as a 'variable'? Can anybody check if the key is protected in any way? If the data is encrypted and then just stored in the same database, I cannot see the point. I don't see any IV or integrity checks either.

Comment: This is an old issue but it's probably worth pointing out that the encrypt module can utilise a key file that's outside the http root of the site. So it's (a) not in the database and (b) not even in the normal code area. Which means both the DB and the code could be stolen and any encrypted data still couldn't be decrypted.

I wrote the original version of the field_encrypt module (http://drupal.org/project/field_encrypt) for D7 which does for standard fields what was being requested here for CCK.